# Aligning position sticky at the bottom right is not working

Tags: css, position, alignment, sticky

I need this button to stick at the bottom right of the screen, but as you can see there's something wrong with my code. What am I missing?

Can you help?
Thanks.

```css
html {
  background: #ccc;
}

.chat {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background: red;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="chat"></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.chat {
 width: 55px;
 height: 55px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 20px;
 left: 20px;
 background: red;
 border: 0;
 }
```

position: fixed is key element.

Comment: But then it is not sticky.

Answer (score 3):

You can reach it with using `float: right;`.

```css
html {
  background: #ccc;
}

.chat {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background: red;
  border: 0;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<button class="chat"></button>
```

Comment: This fixed the horizontal placement (`right`) issue but not the vertical placement (`bottom`) issue